# Error when trying to export to a jar using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I have a java file which runs normal in Eclipse but utilizes the apache commons FTP packages for some utilities.  The issue I am running into is that after several days, it seems to just stop running with no errors.  I believe this may be due to the Eclipse environment it is running in, so following advice of someone else, I tried to export this as a jar, and upon doing so I receive the following error:

Error screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp1b0.png

My end-goal is that I would like this java program which runs fine in Eclipse to be an executable standalone that I can simply leave running somehow.

Comment: Please avoid screenshots, prefer a copy-paste of text.

Comment: @Aubin -- The window wouldn't let me copy paste the text .. sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The screenshot shows your are compiling a library. I suggest you to use a binary, pre compiled one.
2. To run a Java program you have to launch java -cp xxx.jar;yyy.jar...

To make the thing simple, you have to compile and package your code into a jar, without its dependencies. This may be done with the Eclipse wizard *Export as Jar* or with a [ANT script](http://ant.apache.org/).

To manage complex dependencies [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) may be used.

A lot of tutorial exists about Eclipse and how to export a Jar, 5 images follow, to show each step of this process:

[image: Launch the wizard]

[image: Select classes to add]

[image: Check the warning and give a name]

[image: Let eclipse generate the MANIFEST]

[image: Some warnings may be shown]

Comment: This is the error I receive when I try to use the Export as Jar wizard.  Am I doing something wrong?